# Isn't Mind–body dualism the result of a Complex Universe?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-physics, mind-body, dualism

[Mind–body dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism), or mind–body duality, is a view in the philosophy of mind that mental phenomena are, in some respects, non-physical, or that the mind and body are distinct and separable.

Isn't Mind–body dualism the result of a [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) Universe (Where the body is in the [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) part while the mind is in the [imaginary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) part)?

Comment: It seems to me you are reading too much into the terms 'real' and 'imaginary' in the context of complex numbers; we could instead could call them 'a-components' and 'b-components', and their mathematical behaviour would not change. Additionally, the cartesian representation you describe is not the only way of representing complex numbers - they can also be represented in polar form. Don't be misled by maths terms identical to lay terms, but having a specific technical meaning in maths (cf. many people treating a mathematical 'category' as not having a specific mathematical meaning).

Comment: It would be necessary to reduce all complexity for a fundamental theory and so both Mind and Body would have to go. If they remain then our theory is non-reductive. Hence mind-only and matter-only theories are non-reductive. This might be called the central problem of metaphysics although it isn't a problem so much as a challenge.  .

Comment: +1 I added another up vote. I don't agree that mathematics is the way to resolve the mind-body dualism. It reminds me of many worlds using mathematics to come up with its fantasy lands, but I think your questions should be answered courteously.

Comment: No, this is a complete non sequitur. You're just choosing two things that are diametrically opposed and saying "don't these two things relate to these other two diametrically opposed things?" Or, probably worse, you're conflating two different uses of the word "imaginary", i.e. "the mind isn't physical so it must be imaginary so it's like imaginary numbers". This is a [non sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)) [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation).

Comment: @Not_Here
[The quantum mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mind) or quantum consciousness
 group of hypotheses propose that classical mechanics **cannot** explain consciousness . It posits that quantum mechanical phenomena, such as **quantum entanglement** and
**superposition** , may play an important part in the brain's function and could form the basis of an explanation of consciousness.

Comment: The Decartes delusion of mind-body duality has long lost any status of scientific proposition and is purely a religious construct at present

Comment: @amphibient
 What is a neural signal? A neuron , also known as a neurone (British spelling) and nerve cell , is **an electrically excitable cell** that **receives, processes, and transmits information** through **electrical** and chemical **signals**.

Comment: @amphibient
[QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) inside brain!? It is not the Decartes delusion, not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting debate. Not sure about what? But I do agree that there is no place in a logical argument for the irrelevant. As to 'mind', I have (introspectively) tried to find it, so that I could describe it (not explain it - which is not possible to do about anything (the why? of it)). I could find nothing,in the absence of its ephemeral content (that which lasts only for as long as it is required).

Answer (score 1):

Like @Alexis's comment says, you're improperly reading way too much into complex analysis, i.e., your interpretation's beyond unwarranted -- it's "not even wrong". Both here and in your preceding identical post [Is the Universe real or complex?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49746/)

For example, Electricity&Magnetism textbooks universally describe electromagnetic phenomena using complex analysis, e.g., https://books.google.com/books?id=JZNeBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA241 where all those **exp{-iwt}**'s are complex. You wanna make some paranormal interpretation about the real/complex parts of electromagnetic waves? Or would that be beyond absurdly ridiculous? (And I've got a question: Who upvoted this question?)

Comment: -1 For asking who upvoted the question. Your answer was fine until you addressed the questioner personally by writing "You wanna make some paranormal interpretation..." It doesn't matter what the questioner wants to do with the information.

Comment: @John Forkosh
To know what you mean by paranormal, I first need to know what is normal in your opinion? 

If your definition of normal is a world that follows the rules of Newtonian mechanics, then quantum mechanics is paranormal.

Comment: @TheLastJedi I think it would be more apt to say that while quantum mechanics are not paranormal, the concepts are frequently applied haphazardly to unrelated concepts that ARE paranormal.

Comment: @FrankHubeny (also (at)TheLastJedi) Both my "who upvoted" and "wanna make some paranormal interpretation" questions were meant facetiously (which I'd thought was obvious), so I didn't pay much attention to any precise meaning of the terminology. And maybe facetious was unwarranted. But note that I ignored the first "complex number interpretation" post entirely. But when the op quickly repeated the same silliness in this post, I guess I couldn't restrain myself. Just how many more of these same-silly-topic posts should be permitted before a stop-the-silliness reply is considered appropriate?

Comment: @TheLastJedi (also see preceding comment to (at)FH). If pressed to say what I'd mean by "paranormal", it's any phenomenon not reproducibly observable by a well-defined, unambiguous experimental procedure.

Comment: @JohnForkosh
"any phenomenon not reproducibly observable by a well-defined, unambiguous experimental procedure" 

such as [Tachyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon), [cosmic censorship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis), [Quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg's_uncertainty_principle),...[Quantum mechanics in a nutshell!](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Mechanics-Nutshell-Gerald-Mahan/dp/0691137137)

Comment: @TheLastJedi Entanglement and Uncertainty are absolutely experimentally observable, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Aspect (I'll leave you to google around for uncertainty yourself), Whereas tachyons, and arguably censorship, are probably not real in the first place, and therefore not observed.

Comment: I don't want to get on your case. Facetiousness can quickly backfire when misinterpreted. People who are quick to close or belittle questions don't appreciate the opportunities such questions offer. Take the silly question seriously. They may not be all that silly once one considers them. Provide the awesome answer.